# iPad Disable link click through CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, safari

I have multiple links which have the class "disable" defined in CSS.

Now for iPad, I want on click of the link, nothing should happen i.e. link should not get clicked (currently it navigates to some URL)

How do I handle this through CSS only?
I know it can be done through JavaScript/jQuery...But there are a lot of pages and I need to do this through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use this to disable links on my web-apps:

```
a.someClass {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor: default;
}
```

Hope, this will work on the `iPad` too. [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksLT4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't be done in `CSS`.

**But**, as you said that there are lots of `pages`, so you do not able to change everywhere, its false.

You can create a common `javascript file` and add it in every pages.

You can use this code in `jquery`

```
$('.disable').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [trick](http://jsfiddle.net/cFTxH/1/):

```
<button disabled>Hello World</button>


// This will never run
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    });
});

button {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: Blue;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```